# Visual Studio - Keyboard Shortcut to close Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts, solution-explorer

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> Opens Solution Explorer in Visual Sutdio.

But I'm unable to close it with the same keyboard shortcut.

As I need to do this often (to get more real estate on the screen), how do you close the Solution Explorer with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: not by default you can go and make your own i  believe. Here is a website with all default shortcuts that is easy to sift through (https://www.dofactory.com/reference/visual-studio-shortcuts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the following command with [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) (language: C#) and assign a shortcut to close Solution Explorer:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        var serviceProvider = package as System.IServiceProvider;
        var shell = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIShell)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsUIShell));
        var SolutionExplorer = new System.Guid(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.ToolWindowGuids80.SolutionExplorer);
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsWindowFrame frame;
        shell.FindToolWindow(0, ref SolutionExplorer, out frame);
        frame.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably works, but I ended up moving to Rider which had the `Shift` + `Esc` command built in

Comment: The above comment should actually be considered to be the solution. It works with Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Right-clicking on the close icon provides an option to hide the solution explorer by default. This should allow you to use a keyboard shortcut to access the solution explorer and hide the explorer when you leave.

[image: Here is a visual example]